# How to start Fedora Atomic VM?

Tags: fedora, atomic, kvm

I downloaded a qcow2 image from Atomic official site, but I really frustrated with the steps to start this qcow2 image, and no helpful clear tips from Google.

Anyone can give me some clear hints on how to start the qcow2 vm? Thanks.

The image name is: Fedora-Atomic-25-20170131.0.x86_64.qcow2

Answer (score 3):

The Fedora Atomic Host (FAH) qcow is a cloud image, so it expects a Metadata source. Metadata is all the configuration bits a generic cloud image uses to get configured. Specifically, it requires something that the `cloud-init` package [recognizes](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources.html). You can read more about `cloud-init` [here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). If you just want to fire off some one-off VMs for testing, a tool you can use is [testcloud](http://github.com/Rorosha/testcloud).

Using `testcloud` to launch the VM, you'll be able to log in with the user 'fedora' (which is the default in Fedora based cloud images) and the password 'passw0rd' (you can change this default in the config).

The other option is to download the installer ISO, and then you can install into a fresh VM and not have to worry about metadata at all. You can find that [here](https://getfedora.org/en/atomic/download/), under "Other Downloads" on the right hand side.

The #fedora-cloud channel on Freenode is a good place to check if you have any other questions.