# Login error on fedora 25 atomic host

Tags: virtual-machine, atomic, fedora

I followed the Quick Start Page: http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/quickstart/
to create a virtual machine with Virtual Box on Mac OSX. I created a same iso file as the guide showed to me. It worked and the login interface came out.

[image]

But I can't login with default user name: fedora, password: atomic.
Please help me to figure out what is wrong during the processing.

Comment: didn't you change the password in `user-data`? Did you try logging in with the `ssh` and with the public key?

Comment: You can also try passw0rd as recommended [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267539/how-to-start-fedora-atomic-vm/44161135#44161135)

Comment: This should be posted to [unix.se], by the way

Comment: I created an empty folder and compressed it as an ISO file, and tried user name: fedora, password: passw0rd, and it still did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using virtualbox already I highly recommend using our [vagrant boxes](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/fedora). After you [install vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/) you can then run:

```
# vagrant init fedora/25-atomic-host
# vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

and then `vagrant ssh` will get you an ssh session into the box.

We also have a [page](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/vagrant/about.html) on our fedora developer portal that talks about vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

The quickstart you referenced has you set up the user and password in the cloud-init user-data file.

```
$ vi user-data
#cloud-config
password: atomic
ssh_pwauth: True
chpasswd: { expire: False }

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa ... foo@bar.baz (insert ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub here)
```

Did you define them there?

Comment: can we follow this up in email (atomic@projectatomic.io mailing list) or in IRC (irc.freenode.net #atomic)?  I think we're going to need some interactive debugging here.